# How to resolve microdnf (failing with glib error) in a specific environment?

Tags: docker, redhat-ubi

The problem was identified in the CI/CD environment - they are a group of server machines on redhat 7.9 (docker 19.x)

When trying to run docker build the following line fails:

```
RUN microdnf install yum
```

We are using a redhat image (redhat/ubi9-minimal) as base image. The above command is run on that.

The error:

```
(microdnf:6): GLib-ERROR **: 14:57:32.900: file ../glib/gthread-posix.c: line 1338 (g_system_thread_new): error 'Operation not permitted' during 'pthread_create'
```

We tried the same in other docker servers (on centos 7, docker 20.x) and it worked.

<strike>Because this worked on these machines, I suspect some host os differences are at play</strike>.

<strike>I suspect this is because of docker 19.x</strike>. It is because of redhat/ubi9-minimal image and docker 19.x. (I have confirmed this alternatively).

What can I do to fix the CI/CD machines?

Comment: What Linux distribution (and version) are the ci/cd machines running?

Comment: all the ci/cd machines are rhel 7.6

Answer (score 0):

Check your installed docker engine. I had the same error but was able to solve it after upgrading docker-ce to 24.0.5. In my case "apt update && apt upgrade docker-ce" did the trick.

After upgrading it should look like this:

```
$ docker system info
Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version:    24.0.5
```